# how to make a wifi hotspot from mac when it is connected to wifi

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac, wifi-configuration

I need to make a wifi hotspot from my mac when it is connected to the home wifi . I need to give wifi to few temporary people without giving my home wifi password. So I need to create a wifi hotspot from my macbook when it is connected to home wifi, so I can create a new password from my mac and give it to the temporary users.

**Update**

I tried to share wifi from internet sharing options in macbook , but there is no option to turn on wifi sharing from the wifi connection it has already established .

**With windows**

with windows , this is is possible by following below steps ,

- open cmd as administrator & type, netsh wlan set hostednetwork
  mode=allow ssid=wifinameyouwant key=12345678  and hit enter
- then type, netsh wlan start hostednetwork  , and hit enter
- then go to network and sharing settings and you'll see the new
  network
- then go to adapter settings and right click on the wifi adapter , and
  go to sharing and enable sharing to the temporary network you have
  created

that's it , but I need a solution in Mac

Comment: you can't do this without a second wireless card, or the mac should connect via ethernet cable

Comment: @perreal  but with pc  it is possible. what's wrong with mac ?

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible with any os

Comment: @perreal it is possible with windows .I edited the question by showing how to do this in pc .

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac’s physical Wi-Fi interface can either be connected to a Wi-Fi network or host its own network. It can do only one of these things at a time. You cannot connect to a Wi-Fi network and sharing that Wi-Fi network’s connection over Wi-Fi.

Sharing a Wi-Fi network connection by creating another Wi-Fi network will require a separate physical network interface.

Windows has a useful feature that allows you to create a virtual Wi-Fi adapter interface, making it possible to both connect to a Wi-Fi network and create a Wi-Fi hotspot using the same physical network interface at the same time.

Macs unfortunately don’t have the same sort of virtual network interface feature. To share a Wi-Fi connection over Wi-Fi, you’ll need a separate physical Wi-Fi interface.

[Reference](http://www.howtogeek.com/214053/how-to-turn-your-mac-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/)

Answer (score 0):

As others have state Macs are limited in what you want to do, but there are ways around it besides listed.

Use parallels virtual machine software on your mac to add a windows capability of sharing. Not the best option but does work.

Boot in BootCamp via your Mac and do the same as above.

But third and the best option in my opinion is get a router that allows for this. Asus have wonderful routers that allow up to 2 guest networks that you can also stop sharing your network but just have internet access and you can configure priorities. That's what I usually do and just takes the hassle of booting up your mac anytime people are over. Well worth it.